# Can't run Maven grails app in IDEA: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, maven

I have the Grails project that is managed and compiled by Maven. I'm trying to run application with IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.4. The project is imported into IDEA as Maven project.

When I try ro run or debug application I get an error:

```
Fatal error forking Grails JVM: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    <...>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    <...>
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat
    <...>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat
    <...>
```

I've already installed Tomcat 6 server into IDEA's settings, but I think this is not IDEA's problem but the Maven's one, because running `mvn grails:run-app` in console gives the same result. There is dependency `build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"` in the file `BuildConfig.groovy` too if it's important.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this blog post](http://groovyc.net/?p=29) for more information.  The short version is to move the tomcat plugin out of `BuildConfig` and into your `pom.xml`

Also, make sure you have the line `use pom` inside your `grails.project.dependency.resolution` closure inside `BuildConfig`.

Comment: Thank you, this works for me! The only comment I have is that `use pom` doesn't work in Grails 2.1.0 but the `pom true` does. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#mavenIntegration